# Honey. Is it really alkaline forming?

Tags: nutrition, diet, honey, alkaline

> Honey may be acidic, but, like lemons, it is alkaline-forming in the body. Once in the stomach, it can actually alkalinize your system. In general, your diet should be made up of about 70 percent alkaline-forming and 30 percent acid-forming food.

[Source](https://www.honeycolony.com/article/benefits-of-raw-honey/). Yes, it has its minerals and vitamins but the amounts of sugar it contains are incredibly high in comparison.